# TypeError (no implicit conversion of Array into String) active record on create method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following model

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord {
               :id => :integer,
    :business_name => :string,
         :place_id => :string,
          :surburb => :string,
             :type => :text,
       :created_at => :datetime,
       :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

I am sending a JSON object to my api create method this is my object

```
business_params = {
    :business_name => "Endah Parade",
          :surburb => "Taman Sri Endah",
             :type => [
        [0] "premise",
        [1] "point_of_interest",
        [2] "establishment"
    ],
         :place_id => "ChIJixfh-49KzDERePyk34svbaY"
}
```

In my controller i run the following

business = Business.create!(business_params)

but i get the error `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Array into String)`. My `type` column was defined as this

```
change_column :businesses, :type, :text, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(type, ','))"
```

So at least i know that my type column can accept array but i am not sure why i get this error.

In my Business Model, i added the following as well `serialize :type, Array` but it also doesnt help. I get the same error.

How can i solve this issue?

I am using Rails 5.1

Answer (score 2):

That's because `Rails` uses `type` column by default for `STI` implementation.

Disabling of `STI` should help:

```
class Business
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```

Comment: nice one @igor. got it. i just changed my column name instead

Comment: You should accept the solution as it answers your question, just to reward him, a SO way to say thanks. :)

Comment: @KingsleySimon if you think the question is answered, then accept it to mark it as completed